# I’m confused about “will have to” and “has to.” Which do I use in this sentence?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, future-perfect, future-constructions

> “At every certain hour of the day, the surgeon ___ inspect the blood pressure of the patients.”

To fill in the blank, should I write *will have to* or *has to*? Which is the most correct writing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: _Has to_ means that he must do it now, _will have to_ that he will have to do so in the future. (_At every certain hour_ doesn't make sense.)

Comment: "At every certain hour of the day" seems to be a mix between "at every hour" (meaning hourly) and "at certain hours" (at points in time specified somewhere, not hourly).

Comment: Do you mean "The surgeon has to check the patient's blood pressure every hour" ?

Answer (score 1):

"will have to" means that it's something that the person must do in future.

"has to" means that it's something the person has to do either now or regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but first I'd like to say something about the beginning of your sentence.

"At every certain hour of the day" doesn't make sense. Are you trying to say "At a any given hour of the day"? Or "At certain times in the day"? "At certain hours of the day"?? Not sure exactly what it is your trying to say there but it doesn't make sense the way it written there. Now about the question you asked. The surgeon will check patients (plural) blood pressure. Or The surgeon will have to check the patient's (one singular person's) blood pressure